# Regex for validation of many types of number

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm new to Regex and I would like to know how do I detect the number by Regex in C#, that always display in a format : #,###

Ex : `2 000,000` into `2,000`

Ex : `15 000.000` into `15,000`

Ex : `6.700` into `6,700`

Ex : `.3.3.3` into `0,300`

These are some examples that I'm doing for validation

Comment: why not try parsing the value into a number type (`int, double, decimal`) and then using `string.Format()`? You question is not clear what you expect `,` and `.` to be interpretted as.

Comment: You want matching or replacement? also you dont have any specific format. .3.3.3 is a weird input

Comment: Validation isn't transformation. You must use a regex to validate that your input is ok. .3.3.3 isn't a great input. From my point of view is a crap.

Comment: [\d|\s]+[,|.]\d\d\d is one way or simply [\d|\s]+[,|.][\d]{3}

Comment: @RazvanDumitru : I have to manage all the inputs that user enter in the excel file, I load those data into C# so that is obvious that the user can enter anything in the field, yes it is a crap but we dont just deal with the correct inputs all the time, do we ? I'm looking for another regex for this, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, the question is not very clear.
To get your examples working, you can use e.g.

```
(?:(?<int>\d+)[ .,]?|[.,])
(?<frac>\d+)?
(?:[ .,]\d+)*
```

to match the "integer part" and the "fractional part" divided by `.`, `,` or  (wired, but that is what I read out of your examples - since `15 000.000 => 15,000` and `6.700 => 6,700` I assume a comma seperator everywhere).

**I'm pretty sure I did not get it right!** At least not entirely. The examples you provide look like numbers with different thousands separator, but it seems to have no system.

However, this is what you match with the regular expression above:

```
int | | frac | anything else
----+-+------+--------------
  2 | | 000  | ,000
 15 | | 000  | .000
  6 |.|  70  |
    |.|   3  | .3.3
```

In addition, it matches numbers without fractional part.

### In Detail

```
(?:(?<int>\d+)[ .,]?|[.,])
```

Match decimals (one ore more) and store them in a group named `int`. Match an optional , `.` or `,` thereafter.

*OR*

Match `.` or `,`.

```
(?<frac>\d+)?
```

Optionally match the fraction part (one or more decimals).

```
(?:[ .,]\d+)*
```

Match , `.` or `,` and one or more decimals (repeat this zero or more times).
This last one is to prevent the last parts of e.g. `.3.3.3` to match in subsequent calls.

### Next

Then you can use a MatchEvaluator-Function (here in form of a delegate) to replace the values.

```
var rx = new Regex(@"
        (?:(?<int>\d+)[ .,]?|[.,])
        (?<frac>\d+)?
        (?:[ .,]\d+)*
    ",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
var deDE = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

text = rx.Replace(text, delegate(Match match) {
    int integral;
    int fraction;
    int fraclen = match.Groups["frac"].Length;

    int.TryParse(match.Groups["int"].Value, out integral);
    int.TryParse(match.Groups["frac"].Value, out fraction);

    var val = integral + fraction / Math.Pow(10, fraclen);

    return String.Format(deDE, "{0:0.000}", val);
});
```

The function is called for every match. Inside, I read out the groups, convert them into integers and then create the matched value with `integral + fraction / Math.Pow(10, fraclen)` (integral part + fraction part divided by `10^len` where `len` is the string-length of the fraction part, thus "70" becomes 0.7 by calculating `70/10^2 == 70/100 == 0.7`).

At the end, I return `String.Format` with CultureInfo `de-DE`. This is done because in Germany you use `,` as decimal seperator. There are others too - and there are many other ways to output such a number..

This is just an example.